# Google Chrome Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have just spent the past few hours troubleshooting a weird bug with my website when I realized it is nothing to do with my CSS or HTML, but to do with chrome. For me, I am experiencing an odd bug in google chrome where there a different shaded boxes surrounding certain sites. For example, incognito mode, and the settings menu (It also is affecting my website). I have uninstalled chrome, cleared caches, etc, but to no avail. Internet Explorer displays my site just fine. I have googled this and appear to be the only one with this issue. I have enclosed some images of this issue. I hope you will be able to help since you will probably be the most likely to help answer my question. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnauC.jpg
(The white bars aren't the issue, I added those myself) Ad block isn't the issue it seems.

Comment: It seems you have adblocker installed :) Some anti-virus software also remove ads.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. It probably would be a better fit at [su].

Comment: Did you use F12 tools to inspect those boxes? Remove HTML code until those boxes are gone and investigate your problem from that point.